# For emphasis, whether to use the pronoun “celui” or repeat the noun “sondage”?

Tags: pronoms

In a casual email I just sent:

> Tu as remarqué ça ? Je me suis dit que je me devais de changer « allemand » en « polonais »... (chuchote) sous peine de finir par offusquer les Allemands !
>
> Enfin, il n’y a rien à redire sur l'accent polonais, du moins personnellement, je te le dis ! Car... figure-toi que le polonais s'est bel et bien classé *premier* ***dans un sondage*** réalisé auprès de 20 000 Européens... c'est-à-dire ***dans celui*** pour élire l'accent *le moins* sexy du monde...
>
> Inutile de dire, d’ailleurs, qui a *véritablement* gagné, non ? ;)

I wanted to avoid saying “dans celui” in favour of the repetition of the phrase “dans un sondage” in order to emphasise the joking remark:

> ... classé *premier* ***dans un sondage*** réalisé auprès de 20 000 Européens... c'est-à-dire ***dans un sondage*** pour élire l'accent *le moins* sexy du monde...

As I've never studied French grammar systematically, I'm not sure if I have some leeway in repeating a noun in this particular manner – if only for emphasis.

Comment: I think the actual effect of using the pronoun is opposite of what you seem to assume. *Celui* carries more emphasis than repeating the noun.

Comment: Btw, *chuchote* wouldn't be understood. If, as I now guess, you're looking for an equivalent to an informal (*whispers*) you could maybe write (*en chuchotant :*). At least it should be understood.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hi. Yes, I meant it as "(je) chuchote" and wanted to express it in a single word like "soupir(e)" in order to avoid getting too explanatory.

Comment: En ce qui a trait à ce genre de [sondage](https://fr.babbel.com/fr/magazine/le-francais-langue-de-l-amour) comme celui de Babbel de 2015, ça a sans doute bien plus avoir avec le manque de familiarité avec ces langues voire avec les préjugés que les utilisateurs de l'application peuvent entretenir à leur endroit. Il y a aussi l'histoire de l'Europe. Enfin leur méthodologie n'est pas étayée et l'entreprise vend des services d'apprentissage des langues. Personnellement je choisis de me souvenir que le polonais est une des langues officielles de l'Union et que Marie Curie était Polonaise. Merci !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat *dans celui*, you can omit *dans*.

However, *c'est à dire* isn't the appropriate idiom here. To keep the tongue-in-cheek humour from the original sentence and make the punch line more of a surprise than an obvious opposition, I wouldn't use a contrast conjunction (*"mais", "or"*) but something along the lines of

> Car figure-toi que le polonais s'est bel et bien classé premier
>   dans un sondage réalisé auprès de 20 000 Européens... plus précisément
>   celui pour élire l'accent le moins sexy du monde !

or simply

> un sondage réalisé auprès de 20 000 Européens... le sondage pour élire l'accent le moins sexy du monde !

Comment: Thanks. So for the second "sondage", should I have used the definite article "le" rather than an indefinite "un"? If so, the use of "celui" is fully justified, after all.

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule, but *le* seems more logical here - that survey is probably one of a kind, plus you are expanding on *un*, specifying which exact survey this is about. Repeating *le sondage* adds to the comical effect, though you can use *celui* as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. What do you think of using just "celui" without "plus précisément", then?

Comment: Yes, it works just as well !

Answer (score 0):

À mon avis, dans le contexte décrit, l'emploi de *celui* serait erroné.

*Celui* est un pronom démonstratif qui remplace **un élément** qu'on veut **distinguer parmi d'autres**. Par exemple :

> Car...figure-toi que dans le panel de sondages réalisés auprès de 20 000 Européens... c'est dans celui sur l'image sexuelle que reflètent les accents que le polonais a été déclaré le moins sexy de tous.

Or dans la phrase en question tu ne cherches pas à mettre en valeur un sondage spécifique parmi d'autres mais juste **donner une caractéristique** d'un sondage dont tu viens de parler. Dans ce que tu veux dire la répétition de **un sondage** est naturelle et ne ferait pas porter l'emphase sur le mot ou la situation.

Par ailleurs l'emploi de *c'est à dire* n'est pas justifié ici. *C'est à dire* introduit une explication, or ce que tu donnes est plus une précision pour justifier un point de vue. Tu pourrais dire :

> Car... figure-toi que le polonais s‘est bel et bien classé premier dans un sondage réalisé auprès de 20 000 Européens, sondage (organisé) pour élire l'accent le moins sexy du monde.

Pour faire porter l'emphase sur la situation on pourrait ajouter un adverbe :

> Car... figure-toi que le polonais s‘est bel et bien classé premier dans un sondage réalisé auprès de 20 000 Européens, sondage **précisément** (justement) organisé pour élire l'accent le moins sexy du monde.

Comment: Tout l'humour serait perdu comme ça… Le but c'est bien de distinguer le fait qu'il s'agit d'un sondage plus particulier que ce qu'on croit.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'avoue ne pas voir d'humour ici. En tous cas je ne vois pas comment on pourrait employer *celui* dans le contexte de la question (avec sondage précédé de l'article indéfini) - quelque chose doit m'échapper, donc j'attends de voir comment quelqu'un d'autre justifie l'emploi de celui.

Comment: Pour l'humour, ça me semblait évident, mais je note aussi que l'auteur le précise lui-même dans la question.